# How to match the n:th occurrence of a specific character on every line using regex?

Tags: regex

How do I match the n:th occurrence of a specific character on every line in a text file using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most dialects, you can't. You can only capture the n-th occurence in a capture group. This will capture the 4th "p" in group 2, and you can see its index by the length of group 1:

```
/^((?:.*?p){3}.*?)(p)/
```